# While Cresting Issue in Jira via android programming getting java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory not present

Tags: android, android-studio, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am writing a program to create a jira issue automatically via my code but while useing JerseyJiraRestClientFactory and JiraRestClient i am getting Excetion as

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory not present
```

My code goes:

```
class JiraAuthentication extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        URI jiraServerUri;
        ProgressDialog authentication;
        boolean status = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            try {
                authentication = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                authentication.setMessage("Loging into Jira,Please wait....");
                authentication.show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception in onPostExecute");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                jiraServerUri = new URI(urlConn);
                final JerseyJiraRestClientFactory factory;
                factory = new JerseyJiraRestClientFactory();
                final JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                Log.d(TAG, "restClient.getIssueClient() is " + restClient.getIssueClient().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "restClient.getSessionClient() is " + restClient.getSessionClient().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "restClient.getUserClient() is " + restClient.getUserClient().toString());
                ProgressMonitor progressMonitor=new NullProgressMonitor();
                Iterable<BasicProject> allProjects= restClient.getProjectClient().getAllProjects(progressMonitor);
                /*final NullProgressMonitor pm = new NullProgressMonitor();
                Iterable<BasicProject> allProjects = restClient.getProjectClient().getAllProjects(pm);
                for (BasicProject project : allProjects) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "project is " + project);
                }*/
                if (allProjects != null) {
                    status = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception in doInBackground!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            if (authentication != null && authentication.isShowing()) {
                authentication.dismiss();
            }
            if (status) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

An Getting Exception as:

```
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.ss.bugreport, PID: 12923
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement;
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.isReadable(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:92)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:345)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:315)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:298)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:536)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:506)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:674)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:191)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient$2.call(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:96)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:54)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.getAndParse(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:92)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyProjectRestClient.getAllProjects(JerseyProjectRestClient.java:71)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.ss.bugreport.MainActivity$JiraAuthentication.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:132)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.ss.bugreport.MainActivity$JiraAuthentication.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:104)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ss.bugreport-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ss.bugreport-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.isReadable(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:92) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:345) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:315) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:298) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:536) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:506) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:674) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:191) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient$2.call(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:96) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:54) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.getAndParse(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:92) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyProjectRestClient.getAllProjects(JerseyProjectRestClient.java:71) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.ss.bugreport.MainActivity$JiraAuthentication.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:132) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.ss.bugreport.MainActivity$JiraAuthentication.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:104) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:   Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:           ... 21 more
03-20 13:54:57.071 12923-13327/com.ss.bugreport E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Can Anybody help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: Clean project and run again.

Comment: I did, still the same

Comment: Along with that error i am also getting other errors as  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory